# How to prevent pixel bleeding from rendering sprite-sheet generated with Zwoptex on older iOS device?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, sprite-sheet, zwoptex

I packed up several individual sprites and generated a big sprite-sheet 2048*2048 in size with Zwoptex. But I scale down to match each iOS device such as 2048*2048 for iPad HD, 512*512 for iPhone, etc.

I found out that "Spacing Pixel" option in Zwoptex will effect the result of sprites rendering on device. That value means a space (in pixel) between each individual sprite packing up inside sprite-sheet. For instance, if I set that value too low then there's more chance that pixel bleeding will occur on newer or better device as well as older device. But if I increase that value, the chance lowers and for certain value that is high enough, pixel bleeding (hopefully) won't happen.

Anyway, I set value to around 17-20 which is really high and it consumes valuable space on sprite-sheet. The result is, on iPhone simulator, there's still a problem.

As we can only restricts some devices from install the game for certain iOS version, but iPhone 3GS can still update to newest version thus I need to solve this problem.

So I want to know the solution on how to prevent pixel bleeding problem to occur across all iOS devices ranging from iPhone to iPad (included retina).
It would be great to know any best practice or practical solution on selecting certain value for "Spacing Pixel" between sprites to remove the problem away when rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If only the Simulator shows those artifacts, then by all means ignore them!** None of your users will ever run your app in the Simulator, will they? The Simulator isn't perfect.

A spacing of 2 pixels around each texture atlas sprite frame is enough (and generally recommended) to kill all artifacts caused by pixel bleeding. If you still see artifacts, they're not a direct cause from too little spacing. They can't be.

I'm not sure about Zwoptex, do you actually have to manually create each scaled-down version of the texture atlas? You may be doing something wron there. Try [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.com), I wouldn't be surprised if the artifacts go away just like that.

For example, one type of artifact is caused by not placing objects at integer positions. You may see a gap (usually a black line) between two objects if their position is something like (1.23545, 10.0) and (41.23545, 10.0). Using integer coordinates (1,10) and (41,10) would fix the issues. The difficulty is that this goes all the way up the hierarchy, if these object's parent node is also on a non-integer position you can still experience this line gap artifact.

If you search around you'll find numerous cause and effect discussions for cocos2d artifacts. One thing to keep in mind: do not use the CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL macro. It's not a fix, it doesn't even come close. It kinda fixes the non-integer position artifact and introduces another (much worse IMHO): aliasing/flickering during movement.

Comment: I create different spritesheet version by using the program to automatically generate for me, it's for iPad HD, iPad, and iPhone SD.

I tested the game mainly on iPad 2, but I don't have iPhone 3GS in hand so I'm biased to trust simulator. Anyway I will try that out on real device, if that doesn't solve then I will take a look at CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL value to see if it's set or not, then last one I will see if TexturePacker helps me.

I'll get back to you when I'm done. Thanks.

Comment: Updated:

FYI: I didn't enable that macro.

Using TexturePacker solves my problem.
Generating multiple resolution spritesheets with Zwoptex especially smaller scale size (12.5%), it turns out that the resolution is not POT and TexturePacker detects this.

Anyway I tried using that NPOT spritesheet generated with TexturePacker, and there's no pixel bleeding whatsoever. I guess I will consider switch to use this program.
Thanks!